# How do you group by this in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, group-by, grouping

SQL

```
SELECT DATE
     , SURFACE
     , SIZE1
     , SIZE2
     , SIZE3
     , SIZE4
     , QTY
FROM   TEST_TB
GROUP  BY SURFACE
     , SIZE1
     , SIZE2
     , SIZE3
     , SIZE4
ORDER  BY DATE
     , SURFACE
     , SIZE1
     , SIZE2
     , SIZE3
     , SIZE4
```

[image]

How can I group by SURFACE, SIZE1, SIZE2, SIZE3, SIZE4
and get the earliest date from DATE and add all the QTY?
I want to get the result like showing below but cant get it right...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(date) AS date,
       surface,
       size1,
       size2,
       size3,
       size4,
       SUM(qty) AS qty
  FROM test_tb
  GROUP BY surface,
           size1,
           size2,
           size3,
           size4
  ORDER BY date,
           surface,
           size1,
           size2,
           size3,
           size4;
```

Result:

```
DATE     SURFACE    SIZE1      SIZE2      SIZE3      SIZE4             QTY
-------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01.02.21 2B         1.0        22.3       4000       0                   7
04.02.21 PL         5.3        10.0       3500       0                  10
07.02.21 PL         2.1        10.5       1800       0                   3
07.02.21 PL         4.8        8.0        600        0                   9
```

Your expected value for 2B is wrong. The earliest date is February 1, 2021.